# Why is there a "de" right after "langues européennes" in "L'anglais a importé des langues européennes de nombreux termes désignant la nourriture"

Tags: grammaire

Why is there a "de" in

> L'anglais a importé des langues européennes de nombreux termes désignant la nourriture

I'd translate it literally as "English has imported European Languages of numerous terms designated for food" but I know it means "English has brought numerous terms designated for food from European Languages"

Why is there a random "de"? Can't we say

> L'anglais a importé nombreux termes désignant la nourriture des langues européennes

Edit: I found this in a book